# Images do not fit in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    var images: [String] = ["promotion test 1", "promotion test 2", "promotion test 3", "promotion test 4", "promotion test 5", "promotion test 6"]
    var frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
}


pageControl.numberOfPages = images.count
for index in 0..<images.count {
    frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index)
    frame.size = scrollView.frame.size

    let imgView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
    imgView.image = UIImage(named: images[index])
    self.scrollView.addSubview(imgView)
}
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: (scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(images.count)), height: scrollView.frame.size.height)
scrollView.delegate = self
```

[image: This is a screenshot of my problem]

The images are smaller than the scrollview. So, when I see the first page of the scroll view, I can see some part of the image on the next scroll view as well. I do not know what to change in my code. Can you please tell me what I should change?

Comment: Please show _real_ code. You cannot possibly say `pageControl.numberOfPages = images.count` and all the rest just out in free space like that. That code must be in some _method_. Show that method. Everything depends on _where_ this code is!

Comment: From where do you set these imgView sizes? If it's in `viewDidLoad` method `scrollView.frame` values can be different than final scroll view size

Comment: sorry it is in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you refer to values such as `scrollView.frame`. If you do that at a time when the scroll view's frame is not yet known — for example, in `viewDidLoad` — you're going to get the wrong answer. Postpone that code to a time when the scroll view's frame *is* known.

(Even better, perhaps, just get rid of all that code and use a UIPageViewController instead. It does everything you're doing here, automatically, and probably does it a lot better than you're going to do "by hand".)